# Convert a string "[Value]" to just [Value] in Python

Tags: python, json

An API I'm using with Python expects a JSON formatted input at one point like this:

```
  'type': 'leadlist',
  'filter': [1135],
```

But I can only feed the API this kind of value with Python:

```
  'type': 'leadlist',
  'filter': '[1135]',
```

The value for the key 'filter' is generated like this. Notice that it's a string whether as the first example is "nothing"

```
'filter':f"[{key}]"
```

Is there any way this can not be a string?

Edit: The input expected is not a list. It's the ID (a number) of an element in the software I'm using which somehow is between brackets in the JSON API.

Comment: use module `json`

Comment: What is generating that string? You should fix that to return a `list` not a *string representation of a list*

Answer (score 2):

If you can pass it as a list, which is what I think it expects, then you would do:

```
'filter':[key]
```

So altogether maybe something like:

```
body = {'type': 'leadlist',
        'filter':[key]}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not expect a list. The number between brackets is the unique ID of an element in the software.

My belief is that whoever wrote the Python library for the software I'm using (Mautic) did not think of having to reference IDs of elements between bracket because the software clearly only accepts an ID reference in between brackets but not as a string...

Comment: If the reference expects braces but not a string with brackets, it is taking a list, probably of integers. If it takes only a single integer as well it may be set up for both multiples and singles. You should just put key there without the brackets if it’s just the single one, assuming key is an integer already.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion ten minutes ago and tried passing an integer without brackets and it worked :). I shared the answer below! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I just figured it.

Although the Mautic API seems to expect the number ID of the element to be referenced between brackets, it just happens that it also accepts it as an integer alone even without brackets.

So in this case, the solution is this:

```
  'type': 'leadlist',
  'filter': int(f'{value}'),
```

Comment: Why are you doing int(f’{value}’) when you could just write value or int(value) if it isn’t an integer. The f string is for putting a multiple strings together but in this case you only have one item so it isn’t necessary. Just reference the object.

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 Good point. I was using it before because I was referencing a string and put it between brackets but indeed, now it can be written down as simply as you described :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you really do want the string with brackets to be converted to a python list, you can you ast.literal_eval as so:

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval("[1,2,3]")
>> [1,2,3] #gives a python list
```

This works for most python data structures.